# MDX Calendar period vs Financial Period

Tags: mdx, financial, period

I need to create a calculated measure on a cube measuring costs in the financial YTD.

The dimension available to me has only period values available for the Calendar Period and Financial Period (i.e. 200101, 200102, etc).

[Example Data in Dimension with Financial Year July - June](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF5WD.png)

[Example Data in Dimension with Financial Year Jan - Dec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTp27.png)

As seen in the image, the financial period does not necessarily match the calendar period.

What would be the best approach to calculate the period range for the Financial YTD dynamically?

If today's date is 2016/03/01 and fin year is Jul - Jun then the range should be 201601:201609

If today's date is 2016/03/01 and fin year is Jan - Dec then the range should be 201601:201603

I have tried this, but this will not always be true since clients can set their periods up differently:

Strtomember("[Period].[Fin Period].&[" + FORMAT(IIF(MONTH(NOW()) <= 6, DATEADD("yyyy", -1, NOW()), NOW()), "yyyy") + "07]")

Any Ideas?

Comment: "If today's date is 2016/03/01 and fin year is Jul - Jun then the range should be 201601:201609" ...why is the financial YTD not 201507:201603 ?

Comment: That is how the previous developers have designed the functioning. The financial year is 2016 (meaning July 2015 till June 2016) and we want everything for the financial year from period 1 till the period we are currently in. The Calendar periods would be 201507:201603.